# iOS fat static library & submission

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, static-libraries, submission

I have an iOS fat static library (iphoneos & iphonesimulator), if I was to use this during an app submission would it fail on the grounds that the binary includes iphonesimulator code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no problem. When you link your app for device it simply embed the code for the architecture your are using. So your app compiled for device does not embed code for simulator.